# Object required excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a spreadsheet, and I'm trying to make it to where in any given row, if the cell in column D is empty, but the cell in column A is greater than 1, it deletes the row. However, I'm getting "Object Required" when I try to run it.

```
Sub rowdeletetest()
Dim rowBoat As Integer

For rowBoat = 7 To 980
    If ws.Visible = True Then
    If IsEmpty(Range("D", rowBoat)) = True And Range("A", rowBoat) > 1 Then
    Rows(rowBoat).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    End If
Next rowBoat
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the "Object required" error? When you click "Debug", what is highlighted?

Comment: Is `ws` a global? If so, where is it being set?

Comment: The ws actually ended up being the issue. I had added it in before because I had the for loop set to 1000 but the sheet wasn't large enough and I was getting a 400 error, but deleting it cleared that up. Thanks!! @Comintern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
Sub RowDeleteTest()
    Dim rowBoat As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' change sheet, if required

    For rowBoat =  980 to 7 Step - 1
        With ws
            If .Visible = True Then
                If .Cells(4, rowBoat) = VbNullstring And .Cells(1, rowBoat) > 1 Then
                    .Rows(rowBoat).Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next rowBoat
End Sub
```

**Edit #1**

In case you want to test for formulas, `VbNullstring` is not correct to use:

```
Sub RowDeleteTest()
    Dim rowBoat As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' change sheet, if required

    For rowBoat = 980 to 7 Step - 1
        With ws
            If .Visible = True Then
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(4, rowBoat)) And .Cells(1, rowBoat) > 1 Then
                    .Rows(rowBoat).Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next rowBoat
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem ended up being the ws. It wasn't needed anymore anyway, it was added in due to a previous bug and didn't actually solve that previous bug. Thanks, though!!

Comment: `= vbNullString` is *not* the same thing as `IsEmpty()`. Consider a cell containing the formula `=""`.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
If IsEmpty(Range("D" & rowBoat)) And Range("A" & rowBoat) > 1 Then
'alternately,
If IsEmpty(cells(rowBoat, "D")) And cells(rowBoat, "A") > 1 Then
```

When a function returns a boolean (true/false) value, there is no need to compare to true/false in order to return a true/false.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I'm still getting the error after trying both of those lines.